# Adding image overlay to Google Earth Web

Tags: raster, kml, google-earth, overlay

I am trying to add an image overlay to Google Earth Web. It works fine in Google Earth Pro on my desktop, but I can't seem to make it work in Earth Web. I want to be able to have folders in my project with different base images for the contents of each folder (three folders, one with the google earth base imagery for under summer points and paths, one with a GeoTIFF of winter satellite imagery for winter points and paths, and a third with a similar idea to the winter one).
I have tried two things:

1. Saving my Earth Pro project as a KMZ and then opening that in Earth Web. The first time time one of the image overlays came through but not the other. The second time neither of the overlays came through. Is there something specific to make the overlay save properly in the kmz?
2. Starting a fresh project in Earth Web and basing it in Google Drive. I uploaded my GeoTIFF to my Drive and tried, in the new Earth Web project to go "new feature" -> "tile overlay". I added the link to the image in my Google Drive because I wasn't sure what to put in the "link" field in the tile overlay creation window. Nothing showed up on the project, so clearly that wasn't the right answer either.

How can I add the overlays in Earth Web successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time (end 2022), the Google Earth Web client does not (yet?) support creation of basic image overlays in its content creation tools.  As you found, you can create a Tiled Overlay (if you have the URL for a set of hosted map tiles), but you can't create a basic overlay from a single image.  Earth Web also does not currently support GeoTiff or other GIS data import & conversion like Earth Pro does, though we hope that will come in the future.

That said, you should be able to load a KML/KMZ in Earth web which already contains one or more image overlays (created in Earth Pro or elsewhere), as you tried to do.  There are a number of reasons why it might not work, which depend on what images you're using, how the overlays were created, and where the data is stored or hosted.  If you want help debugging why your current KMZ doesn't work, please provide a copy (or link to) your file if possible, or a sample that shows the issue.  Probably best to post that in a new question focused just on that issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have made the KML/KMZ upload from Earth Pro to Earth Web successful since I posted my question. However, I am then unable to then to share my map as an embedded web map, but need to email it as a KML like with Earth Pro. Unfortunately that limitation will mean that the program won't work for my needs. I'll explore QGIS2WEB next I think.